# Google Apps Scripts - Add specific value to each row being processed in a loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

so I want to write a function that takes leads from a source sheet, and then, sends them to another sheet (the destsheet) if they haven't been sent yet. The difference between a lead that has been sent and a lead that hasn't been is that a lead sent should have "yes" in column K (column 10)

I have managed to get the first part working (sending leads from a sheet to another) but for some reason, I can't get the script to add "yes" when a lead is sent to the other sheet. As you can see below, I've tried adding "values[i][tstCol] = "yes";" in several different spots, but it's not working.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
function newLeads() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');

var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
var finalValues=[];

var columns = String("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8").split(','); //only want these columns
var tstCol = 10; 
for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    var newValues=[];
    //values[i][tstCol] = "yes";
    if (values[i][tstCol] != "yes") {
    //values[i][tstCol] = "yes";
      for (var j=0;j<columns.length;j++) {
      //values[i][tstCol] = "yes";
        newValues.push(values[i][columns[j]]);
      }
      finalValues.push(newValues);
    }
  }
  destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, finalValues.length, finalValues[0].length).setValues(finalValues);
}
```

Comment: About `column K (column 10)` in your question, I think that column "K" is column 11. So I cannot understand your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Are you receiving any errors along with the script execution?

Comment: Where do you want "yes" to be stored, in the array values or in the spreadsheet?  You put "yes" in values[i][10] but you only transfer from 0 to 8 to newValues/finalValues  setValues(finalValues).  And when do you want it stored, right after newValues=[]?  Then the  if block is never executed.

Comment: @tanaike, with GAS, each column index starts at 0, so K would be column 11.

Comment: @ale13, no I wasn't receiving any errors.

Comment: @TheWizEd, I wanted the yes to be stored in the source spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this.

```
function newLeads() {
  try {
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');
    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName('SHEETNAME');

    var values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    var finalValues=[];

    var columns = String("0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8").split(','); //only want these columns
    var tstCol = 10; 
    for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
      var newValues=[];
      if (values[i][tstCol] != "yes") {
        values[i][tstCol] = "yes";  // is this where you want to set to yes
        for (var j=0;j<columns.length;j++) {
          newValues.push(values[i][columns[j]]);
        }
        finalValues.push(newValues);
      }
      values[i] = [values[i][tstCol]];  // this would extract column tstCol
    }
    destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, finalValues.length, finalValues[0].length).setValues(finalValues);
    sourceSheet.getRange(1,tstCol+1,values.length,1).setValues(values);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Explanation:

The `try` block is used to see if an error occurs during the block between `try` and `catch`; if an error occurs, the `catch(err)` block is executed and the error is being displayed.

The `values` array is an array of rows [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],...] which I converted it to an array [[1],[2],[3]...] of a single column of the spreadsheet type in order to use the `setValues(values)` method.

Reference link:

- [Apps Script setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Comment: it works as intended now, thank you so much! I see that you added "      values[i] = [values[i][tstCol]]; " and and a try/catch block to my code, would you mind explaining why?? (I'm learning to code and I want to get better at it :) thanks!)

Comment: I always use a try/catch block.  try is if an error occurs during the block between try and catch the catch(err) block is executed and I display the err.  Its just my preference for coding.  The values array is an array of rows [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],...]  I couldn't use setValue(values) otherwise it might overwrite formulas or something else.  So I convert it to an array [[1],[2],[3]...] which is a single column of the spreadsheet and I can use setValues(values).  1 is the number 1, surrounded by square backets [1] is an array of one value 1.